# Measuring or calculating the pH of 4M NaOH? I prepared the solution in Milli Q water

Tags: acid-base, ph

I prepared $4\ \mathrm{M}$ solution of $\ce{NaOH}$, and the glass electrode I use cannot measure it the $\mathrm{pH}$ correctly. What are the other options do I have to exactly know the solution's $\mathrm{pH}$?

Comment: This link explains the problem. http://www.all-about-ph.com/acid-and-alkaline.html The following link is for a high pH electrode but I couldn't find any specifications for it. :-(  http://www.awedirect.co.uk/ph/ph-electrode/high-alkaline-ph-electrode-9037-10b.html

Comment: Do you really need to know pH or just that solution is 4.00 molar NaOH? Can you assume that the solution is "pure" NaOH? No NaCl, no KOH. I'm wondering about a sodium electrode, or conductivity. Carbonate from the air will be a problem.

Comment: Did you use tap water or distilled water?

Comment: thanks ringo, I had calculated the same way, and I had made it in Miili q water, pH 5.7, and using AR grade NaOH.

Answer (score 1):

For $\mathrm{pH}>12$ and $\ce{Li+}$ or $\ce{Na+}$ concentrations greater than $0.1\ \mathrm{M}$, glass electrodes experience [alkali error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glass_electrode#Range_of_a_pH_glass_electrode). Because the concentration of $\ce{H3O+}$ ions in solution is so low, interference from alkali metal ions (like $\ce{Na+}$) becomes noticeable and causes the electrode to read lower than the true $\mathrm{pH}$ of the solution. $\ce{K+}$ typically cause less error than $\ce{Li+}$ or $\ce{Na+}$ due do its larger size.

Since sodium hydroxide is a strong base and dissociates completely into $\ce{Na+}$ and $\ce{OH-}$ ions, though, it's actually quite simple to just calculate the $\mathrm{pH}$.

$$K_\mathrm{w}=\ce{[H3O+][OH-]} \Rightarrow$$
$$ 1 \times 10^{-14} \ \mathrm{M^2}=\ce{[H3O+] \cdot 4\ \mathrm{M}} \Rightarrow $$
$$\ce{[H3O+]}=2.5 \times 10^{-15}\ \mathrm{M}$$
$$\mathrm{pH}=–\log(2.5 \times 10^{-15}\ \mathrm{M})=14.60$$

If you are worried about whether or not you truly have a $4\ \mathrm{M}$ solution of $\ce{NaOH}$, you should try titrating it with a known concentration of acid (in the past I always used [potassium hydrogen phthalate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_hydrogen_phthalate)). This process is called standardization in acid-base parlance.

Comment: I am pretty sure that is not 'exact'. If the electrode cannot measure it, there is a decent chance, that the final solution does not behave like an ideal solution.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Addressed this